# get text of the first li element from every ul

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a lot of `<ul>` list and try to get from every first li of this list the text.

the markup is simple like:

```
<ul>
   <li>abc</li>
   <li>def</li>
   <li>ghi</li>
</ul>
```

and so on.

my jQuery attempt is:

```
    var elems = $('ul'); // returns a nodeList
    var arr = jQuery.makeArray(elems);
    arr.reverse(); // use an Array method on list of dom elements

    for( var i=0;  i < elems.length; i++) {
        console.log($(this).find('li:lt(1)').text());
    }
```

But I have a mistake in the `for` loop with `$(this).` I don't know how to get the first text of `ul` number 1 or 3 if i don't use `$(this).`

So how can point it correctly in the `for` loop?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`.each` will give you `this`.

```
$('ul').each(function() {
     console.log($(this).find('li').eq(0).text());
})
```

Comment: Would $("li").first().text() work equally as well here or no? (inside the .each, of course)

Comment: That would get the first LI on the page - you need 'this' to get the current UL's scope.

Answer (score 2):

Alternative sytax using `:first` instead of `:eq(0)`

```
  $('ul').each(function() {
     console.log($(this).find('li:first').text());
  });
```

or, to forgo the `find()` function.

```
 $('ul').each(function() {
    console.log( $('li:first', this).text() );
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

you can also use:

```
$("li:nth-child(1)").each(function() 
                              {
                                console.log($(this).text());
                              });
```

**notes:**

- with `:nth-child(n)`, all children are counted, regardless of what they are.
- with `:nth-child(n)`, n is 1-based (the first index is 1 instead of 0)